# Make Hidden Repeater Columns Visible Weirdness in C#

Tags: c#, repeater

I have a repeater with a group of columns hidden until a button is clicked to reveal them. This works fine until you click the button again which results in hiding the columns again.

I basically want it to work once and no more (I may put a clear/reset in though). I've tried if statements etc in the foreach loop with no luck.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuote" OnItemCommand="rptQuote_ItemCommand" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p>
            <span><%#Eval("Qty") %> x&nbsp;</span> 
            <span class="bolist120"><%#Eval("product") %> bin</span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBinPrices" Visible="false">@ <%# string.Format("{0:c}",Eval("Value")) %> = <%# string.Format("{0:c}",Eval("Total")) %></asp:Label> 
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" OnClick="BtnCalc" />
```

Here's onclick code:

```
protected void BtnCalc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptQuote.Items)
    {
        var label = (Label)item.FindControl("lblBinPrices");
        label.Visible = true;
    }

}
```

I was wondering if I'm loosing the *label.Visible = true;* on the next click, but then surely the onclick action should set it back again.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers,
Numb

Comment: Question: 1. What is happening in `rptQuote_ItemCommand`? 2. Are you binding data to `rptQuote` after button click by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier to do with JQuery on the client side. Instead of using the Visible property and changing that during a postback (high overhead), use a style property to hide the hidden stuff, then use JQuery to show it. Something like this...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuote" OnItemCommand="rptQuote_ItemCommand" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p>
            <span><%#Eval("Qty") %> x&nbsp;</span> 
            <span class="bolist120"><%#Eval("product") %> bin</span>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBinPrices" Visible="false">@ <%# string.Format("{0:c}",Eval("Value")) %> = <%# string.Format("{0:c}",Eval("Total")) %></asp:Label> 
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<input type="button" id="bt_showStuff" value="Click to show stuff" />
```

Then, you simply use the class property of your hidden stuff to find it, and a click event on the button...

```
$("#bt_showStuff").click(function() { 
    $(".hiddenClass").prop("visible", "visible");
} );
```

So, that means, when you click on the button, JQuery will find all the elements with the "hiddenClass" class, and change their "visible" property to "visible" - your page should send it out as "visible: hidden;" - this will only work once. Once the stuff is "visible" setting it to "visible" again won't matter. You could also hide the button itself as part of your click event...

```
$("#bt_showStuff").click(function() { 
    $(".hiddenClass").prop("visible", "visible");
    $("#bt_showStuff").fadeOut();
} );
```

This would prevent someone from clicking the (now non-functional) button again.

(In your code sample, I can't tell which things you want to be hidden. I can fix the code above to be fully functional if you can tell me that)

Comment: Thanks for that.My thinking was to us code behind as the button click will do other stuff as well (send an email and update a table). But ya right, Jquery would be better for this. I want to show everything inside the label - Eval("Value") and Eval("Total"). Cheers.

Comment: So, showing the supplemental information causes an email to be sent? You would need to use code-behind page for that, but that seems like an odd UI, maybe I didn't understand?

Comment: All working using JQuery. Much better! The page is to show a quotation to a perspective client, click the button to 'calculate' ie reveal the price and then email the quoted details to the sales team. Thanks for your help...

Comment: Make your "show" button show the calcs *and* a server button control that sends the email that way you can cause a post-back and handle the event normally to send your email, but they can't see or use that button till they 'show' it.